# Proving that $\mathbb{N}$ is in bijection between an infinite proper subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that for any finite subset $F \subset \mathbb{N}$, one has $|\mathbb{N} - F| = |\mathbb{N}|$.

I'm not sure if my idea is on the correct track, but here's what I'm thinking. As $F$ is finite, $\mathbb{N} - F$ is infinite. So I can write down a bijection by "listing its elements in order." So I'll define $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} - F$ by defining $f(1)$ equal to the smallest element of $\mathbb{N} - F$ (using the Well-ordering principle), $f(2)$ to be the smallest element of $(\mathbb{N} - F) - \{f(1)\}$, and upon defining $f(1), \ldots, f(n-1)$ for some $n \geq 2$, I define $f(n)$ to be the smallest element of $(N - F) - \bigcup\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n-1} f(i)$. The map is then strictly increasing because, at every step, I discarded the smallest element. Therefore, it's injective. It's also surjective because, if not, there exists $x \in (\mathbb{N} - F) - f(\mathbb{N})$, which implies that $x > n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N} - F$, which isn't possible because $\mathbb{N} - F$ is infinite.

How does this look? My main hesitation is that I didn't write down a map from $\mathbb{N} - R$ to $\mathbb{N}$, though I'm not certain there is as natural a way to do that.

Comment: I’m not sure if this observation implicitly uses deeper set theory, but: if this were not true, $\Bbb N\setminus F$ would have to be finite. This cannot be.

Comment: He map $\Bbb N\setminus R\to\Bbb N$ is just the inverse. It is equally natural. Send the smallest element to $1$: remove it. Now send the new smallest element to $2$. Et cetera

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is perfect as it is. To show that you have a bijection between two sets you actually have two options — show that the map has an inverse or that it is both injective and surjective. You showed the latter which is just fine. You can check that these two conditions are indeed equivalent.